# Frying my brain trying to understand linear interpolation formula relation

Tags: opengl

In pure mathematics, using Wikipedia as source where it describes how the formula is derived for linear interpolation, I understand the equation

```
y = y0 + (x-x0)*(y1-y0)/(x1-x0)
```

without problems.

But in OpenGL and general image processing when dealing with linear interpolation the same formula is given as

```
(a,b) interpolated a * (1-t) + bt where 0<=t<=1
```

and I don't understand the relationship here at all. How are these two equations related? Whats the maths between them, it makes no sense whatsoever. I have tried to understand this from every way I could think of but without success.

I need to know this so I can manipulate shaders to do what I need them to do since all of the OpenGL functions are revolved around the second formula.

So can somebody kindly explain their relationship between this equations?

I have tried searching linear algebra textbooks and such an explanation doesn't exist, and in computer graphics textbooks they don't give any description just mention it as a formula and nothing more, its like some kind of unwritten secret or something.

Comment: The [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation), describes it at the end of the article (`lerp`) `v0 + t * (v1 - v0)` or `(1 - t) * v0 + t * v1` is a special case of your first function, then the interval of `x` is  `0` to `1`.

Comment: @Rabbid76 is that for linear extrapolation?

Comment: in this picture of that geometric visualization https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation#/media/File:Linear_interpolation_visualisation.svg

shouldnt the sum of the multiplication of those length you mention equal y and not y*(x1-x0) as shown in the picture? thats whats confusing me right now

Comment: then whats the green horizontal arrow for? and why is it been multiplied by y(as in the original equation)? when the equation just shows y = .....

Comment: @Rabbid76 that analogy is very nice and thank you for that, but in that picture it doesnt coincide with that explanation , because it is saying y *(x1-x0) = the sum of those other things which make sense, when the equation ays y = the sum of those other things, there seems to be a contradiction, i think its a mistake

Comment: okay i figured it out, sorry im pretty sure i am retarded after this, i was thinking that the picture coincided with y*(x1-x0) = y1*t + y0*(1-t) but clearly the picture is saying y*(x1-x0) = y1*(x-x0) + y0*(1-(x-x0))

Comment: since you helped me first, if you like present a summarized answer u mentioned above and i will accept your answer

Answer (score 3):

The equations are the same, the variables just have different names, and some of them have fixed values.

Start with the Wikipedia definition:

> y = y<sub>0</sub> + (x-x<sub>0</sub>)*(y<sub>1</sub>-y<sub>0</sub>)/(x<sub>1</sub>-x<sub>0</sub>)

Now, substitute:

> y<sub>0</sub> = a
>
> y<sub>1</sub> = b
>
> x<sub>0</sub> = 0
>
> x<sub>1</sub> = 1
>
> x = t

We get the following formula out of that:

> y = a + (t-0)*(b-a)/(1-0)

We can simplify and rearrange:

> y = a + t*(b-a)
>
> y = a + tb - ta
>
> y = a(1-t) + bt

The resulting formula is the same.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you need a value `x`in [a,b] range.

You can say `x` is a *combination* of both extremes. If you use 100% of 'a' then you use 0% of 'b'. If 60% of 'a', then 40% of 'b'.

Generally if you use `t` of 'b' then you use `1-t`of 'a'. The condition `0 <= t <= 1` just ensures you get `x` in [a,b] range. Other `t` values will ive you a `x` outside of that range.

---

Now, how is this related to the equation of a point in the segment [A,B]?

Being A={x0,y0} and B={x1,y1} any point in this line is 'A' plus some portion of the [A,B] segment. This addition must be done component by component:

```
x= x0 + k(x1-x0)
y= y0 + k(y1-y0)
```

Note the same `k` in both equuations of this *parametric definition*, so as to keep the angle of the line, which is the same as keeping the proportion `(y1-y0)/(x1-x0)`

If you derive `k` in both equations, and equal them you get the formula

```
y= y0 + (y1-y0)/(x1-x0) * x
```

OK. Let's continue.

The formula `a(1-t) + bt` if applied to a segment (a,b) must be also operated by components:

```
res.x = a.x * (1-t) + b.x * t
res.y = a.y * (1-t) + b.y * t
```

or with x,y notation:

```
x= x0 * (1-t) + x1 * t  =  x0 - x0 * t + x1 * t  =  x0 + (x1-x0) * t
y= y0 * (1-t) + y1 * t  =  y0 - y0 * t + y1 * t  =  y0 + (y1-y0) * t
```

which is the same as the parametric definition

Answer (score 1):

There are already good answers to your question, this is just to add a little reasoning to second equation

The second example is the beginnings of `BaryCentric Interpolation` which in a 2D sense isn't all that meaning full.

But it does allow the interpolation equation to go into N Dimensions. For example `BaryCentric Interpolation` is how values are calculated across a triangle going from the vertex shader into the fragment shader.